# Automotive technology Sherpa

Tags: can

My goal is a phone application that will send and receive messages with my car. My Google searches keep putting me in the wrong place on this protocol stack. I think I simply need clarification of the terminology because it appears there is some ambiguity, at least on my part.

I suspect that there is already open source code running on Android that can send and receive messages with the information system in my car, and I'm aware that there are several of them, CAN, MOST, LN, and so on. I expect that these are hardware protocols, for the most part, and "hidden" beneath the public interfaces of the car, by which I mean Bluetooth and USB. Am I correct in my assumptions? I think I would benefit from seeing that code. Perhaps there is simply a Wi-Fi router that connects to the OBD II port and presents a Wi-Fi interface. That might also be a good example to review.

I seek an open source example of an Android application sending and receiving messages with my car.

Can anybody advise me?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Onboard Bluetooth to CAN? Not usually - it’s a security nightmare. A few years ago some people managed to compromise the infotainment unit in a Jeep and then compromise its internal CAN bridge to get internet to vehicle bus connectivity. That was considered epic in hacking communities but bad in the automotive ones:

https://www.wired.com/2015/07/hackers-remotely-kill-jeep-highway/

Automakers work hard to keep the unsecured and unsecurable busses away from remote attackers. This is probably why you have not found your Sherpa.

You’ll have to attach a product to your vehicle to enable this functionality, I recommend searching for “OBD2 Bluetooth”

As to open source android vehicle stuff, I feel that it exists but I don’t know of any. A quick search for "Android OBD2 open source" got me this - good luck:

https://github.com/fr3ts0n/AndrOBD